# Unable to install apache spark 1 on HDP 2.6

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm a beginner in Spark. I have been trying to learn Spark with Scala by installing HDP 2.6 on VMWare Workstation. And I use PuTTY for connecting to the server and practicing, I could install scala and java in the same.
When I tried to install Spark (tar -xvf spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz), it gets unzipped but when I type "spark-shell" it shows command not found.

Please suggest what to do

Comment: Is it a hortonworks sandbox?

Comment: Yes it is Hortonworks sandbox

Comment: Then why are you installing spark 2.x of HDP 2.7 and you got HDP 2.6. you've also mentioned spark 1 in the heading and trying to download spark 2. Let me tell you one thing hortonworks sandbox comes with both the version. Just do "export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 " in terminal for spark 2 and "export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=1" for spark 1.

Comment: sorry, now i mentioned the correct version please have a look

Comment: I've re edited the comment section check.

Comment: okay, I'm not trying to install Spark 2 because the project requirement is spark 1. will typing  "export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=1" resolve the "spark-shell: command not found" issue?

Comment: Please go through this link https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/spark-on-yarn-example/

Comment: Check the topic 9 "Spark on YARN example"